# How to find infinite set $X$, which satisfies $T(n)=Ω(n)$ when $n∈X$

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

Consider the following recurrence relationship.

\begin{eqnarray}
T(n) &=&
\begin{cases}
    T\left(\displaystyle\frac{n}{2}\right) + 1, &n \ \mbox{is even number}& \\
    2T\left(\displaystyle\frac{n-1}{2}\right),　&n \ \mbox{is odd number}&
\end{cases} \nonumber \\
T(1) &=& 1
\end{eqnarray}

How to prove there exists an infinite set $X$, that when $n∈X$, $T(n)=Ω(n)$?

Comment: $T(n)=\Omega(n)$ definition usually means $n \to \infty$ type aproximation. What you understand under $n \in X$?

Comment: @zkutch Thank u for replying. I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Definition for $T(n)=\Omega(n)$ is $\exists N,C$ such, that $T(n)\geqslant C \cdot n$ for $\forall n \gt N$. So set here is $(N, +\infty)\cap \mathbb{N}$. Now about which $n \in X$ are you asking?

Comment: @zkutch what if we change the definition of Ω, the set is now (N,+∞) ∩ X

Comment: @zkutch: $T(n)=\Omega(n)$ is short for $\exists S(n):S(n)=\Omega(n)\land \forall n\in X:T(n)=S(n)$.

Comment: @Yves Daoust. 
I put the question in order to get an answer from the OP, because it would help him understand what he is being told. Well, in general, for example, in the definition of the asymptotics in De Bruijn - Asymptotic methods in analysis - 1958 page 4, it is actually only about the $\in$ type of constraints.

Comment: @zkutch: the OP understands the special $\Omega$ condition, I guess.

Comment: @Yves Daoust, I agree with your guess, but I think OP has problems with the concept of definition initially. Look what he asks after Yuval Filmus's answer.

Comment: @zkutch: that's probably because Yuval's answer does not express $T(n)$ explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the idea. When $n$ is even,
$$ \frac{T(n)}{n} \approx \frac{1}{2} \frac{T(n/2)}{n/2}. $$
In contrast, when $n$ is odd,
$$ \frac{T(n)}{n} \approx \frac{T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)}{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}, $$
due to the factor 2 in the recurrence.

This suggests that in order to find your set $X$, you want to hit the "odd" case all the way. If $m = \frac{n-1}{2}$ then $n = 2m+1$, so if $m$ is a good choice, so is $n$. This suggests considering the sequence defined by $n_0 = 1$ and $n_{t+1} = 2n_t+1$, which is $1,3,7,15,\ldots$. As you can see, $n_t = 2^{t+1}-1$. The value of $T$ on this sequence is $1,2,4,8,\ldots$, that is, $T(n_t) = 2^t$.

We can now prove by induction that $T(2^{t+1}-1) = 2^t$. When $t = 0$, this just states the base case $T(1) = 1$. When $t > 0$,
$$
T(2^{t+1}-1) = 2T\left(\frac{2^{t+1}-2}{2}\right) = 2T(2^t-1) = 2\cdot 2^{t-1} = 2^t.
$$
Finally, note that
$$
T(2^{t+1}-1) = 2^t \geq \frac{1}{2} (2^{t+1}-1),
$$
and so you can take $X = \{ 2^{t+1}-1 : t \in \mathbb N \}$ as your infinite set.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I am still thinking why it is ()=Ω().Could you explain more if you can?

Comment: I suggest taking a deeper look at the definition.

Answer (score 0):

If all arguments of $T$ are even, i.e. when $n$ is a power of $2$, the solution of the recurrence is $T(n)=\log_2(n)+1$. (Because $\log_2(2^k)+1=\log_2(2^{k-1})+1+1$.)

On the opposite, when all arguments of $T$ are odd, the solution is $T(n)=\dfrac{n+1}2$ (Because $\dfrac{n+1}2=2\dfrac{\dfrac{n-1}2+1}2$.)

---

**Resolution of the second recurrence**:

For all odd arguments,

$$T(n)=2T\left(\frac{n-1}2\right)$$ becomes, with the ansatz $T(n)=an+b$,

$$an+b=2a\left(\left(\frac{n-1}2\right)+b\right),$$ giving $a=b$. Then the initial condition makes $a+b=1$.